# Using arrays instead of regular loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working code and it works fine for small amounts of data

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim myAreas     As Areas
Dim c           As Range
Dim sTemp       As String
Dim lr          As Long
Dim i           As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
    'Refers to the worksheet using ws as variable to refer to it
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'Determine the last row based on column 9 (Column I)
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

    'Determine the areas separated by empty row so as to deal with each block of data
    'And this will be based on column I
    Set myAreas = ws.Range("I2:I" & lr).SpecialCells(2).Areas

    'Change the format of column I to be as Text
    ws.Columns(9).NumberFormat = "@"
    ws.Columns("AN:AO").NumberFormat = "@"

    'Loop through the areas (blocks of data)
    For i = 1 To myAreas.Count

        'Empty the variable because we will use it again
        sTemp = Empty

        'Extend the block to include 38 columns after column I
        With myAreas(i).Resize(, 38)
            'Debug.Print .Address 'Gives you the address of the range

            'Sort data by column I which is the first column in that range
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

            'loop through cells in column I
            For Each c In .Columns(1).Cells

                'Adjust the format of the cell
                c.Value = AddZeros(c.Value, 2)

                'if the cell value="01 or "11" then the inside lines will be executed
                If c.Value = "01" Or c.Value = "11" Then

                    'Put asterisk in the column AM and AP
                    c.Offset(, 30).Value = "*": c.Offset(, 33).Value = "*"

                    'Cell in AO column equals to cell in AN
                    c.Offset(, 32).Value = c.Offset(, 31).Value

                    'Foramt number to be equal to 9 length
                    c.Offset(, 31).Value = AddZeros(c.Offset(, 31).Value, 9)
                    c.Offset(, 32).Value = AddZeros(c.Offset(, 32).Value, 9)
                End If
            Next c
        End With

        'Deal with the block again
        With myAreas(i).Resize(, 38)

            'Loop through column S cells
            For Each c In .Columns(11).Cells

                'if cell value not empty and not equal 0 then
                If Trim(c.Value) <> Empty And Trim(c.Value) <> 0 And Trim(c.Value) <> "" Then

                    'put the cell value into the variable sTemp
                    sTemp = Trim(c.Value)
                End If
            Next c

            'Loop again through cells in column S
            For Each c In .Columns(11).Cells

                'if cell in column J equals 01 or 11 then the cell value will be equal to sTemp
                'else leave it empty
                If c.Offset(, -10).Value = "01" Or c.Offset(, -10).Value = "11" Then c.Value = sTemp Else c.Value = Empty
            Next c

            'Loop again through cells in column S to fill the empty names
            For Each c In .Columns(11).Cells
                If c.Value = "" Or c.Value = Empty Then c.Value = c.Offset(-1).Value
            Next c

            'Loop through column AE
            For Each c In .Columns(23).Cells

                'If cell value is a number the convert it to positive
                If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then c.Value = Abs(c.Value)

                'trim the value in cell in column AL
                c.Offset(, 7).Value = Trim(c.Offset(, 7).Value)

                'Column J equals to 1208643 then
                If c.Offset(, -21).Value = "1208643" Then
                    'Column J next row cell
                    c.Offset(1, -21).Value = "800107"

                    'Column P next row cell
                    c.Offset(1, -15).Value = "1050-101"
                End If

                'if the value in cell in column AE is number and the value in column J equals 1208643 then
                If IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Offset(, -21).Value = "1208643" Then
                    c.Offset(, -1).Value = "A0"
                ElseIf IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                    c.Offset(, -1).Value = "A1"
                End If
            Next c
        End With
    Next i
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done...", 64
End Sub

Function AddZeros(makeLonger As String, numberDigits As Integer) As String
Dim x           As Long
For x = 1 To (numberDigits - Len(makeLonger))
    makeLonger = "0" & makeLonger
Next x
AddZeros = makeLonger
End Function
```

However when trying it with large amounts of data about 60,000 rows it took so much time .. so is it possible to optimize it to make it faster?

The code is looping through the specialcells in column I to get the areas (blocks of data) and sort each block and also do some calculations based on cells values in some columns ..

I have posted it at stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771159

Comment: Ok I have a few questions before I give it a go. 1) Is setting an area even useful b/c you can just set the loop to ignore the current state o the array if arrayposition(whatever, whatever) was blank? 2). Wjy are you reszing the areas? 3) wouldnt one loop do the trick here?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Loops are necessary as for each loop, a specific task is required and the next loop will be dependent on the results of the previous loop..

Comment: Replacing `AddZeros()` with `Format(makeLonger,String(numberDigits,"0"))` will help.  e.g. `c.Offset(, 31).Value = Format(c.Offset(, 31).Value, String(9, "0"))`

Comment: Thanks a lot TimMan for this hint.

Comment: I have replaced the lines which I used AddZeros with your sugesstion and it works well. But when compared the time I have noticed there is no difference between both methods